# Component size query of mutable 3D array graph (Dynamic connectivity)

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, tree, graph-theory

### Goal

I'm trying to simulate a ship with a voxel representation, in a 3D bool array where `true` represents empty space and `false` represents a hull block of the ship. Any hull block can be damaged and repaired. Components formed with empty space inside the hull is filled with air. A component that is breached (connected to the outside of the ship) is filled with water.

I need to find out after damage/repair whether a position is in air or in water. If it is in air, I need to know the volume of this component.

### Properties

`Size.x, Size.y, Size.z <= 300` and the ratio of `true` in the array greatly exceeds the number of `false` in it (ratio greater than 5:1).

### Example

Consider this abstract data type, a 3D bool array that allows point update (damage/repair), and query of the size of the component containing a given position, and whether this component touches the boundary of the array (water):

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    Vec3 Size { get; }       // size of the array
    bool Get(Vec3 pos);      // get the value at pos
    void SetTrue(Vec3 pos);  // set the value at pos to true
    void SetFalse(Vec3 pos); // set the value at pos to false
    
    // Check whether the component is closed.
    // Closed means that it doesn't contain any position on the boundary of the array.
    // If it is closed, return the size of the component
    // Otherwise, return -1
    int GetComponentSize(Vec3 pos);
}
```

Here is my naive implementation of the ADT, with `O(1)` update time and `O(n)` query time where `n` is the query result:

```
public class MyClass : MyInterface
{
    private readonly bool[,,] _A;
    public Vec3 Size { get; private set; }

    public MyClass(Vec3 size)
    {
        Size = size;
        _A = new bool[size.x, size.y, size.z];
    }

    public bool Get(Vec3 pos)      => _A[pos.x, pos.y, pos.z];
    public void SetTrue(Vec3 pos)  => _A[pos.x, pos.y, pos.z] = true;
    public void SetFalse(Vec3 pos) => _A[pos.x, pos.y, pos.z] = false;

    private static Vec3[] _dirs = {
        new Vec3(-1, 0, 0),
        new Vec3(0, -1, 0),
        new Vec3(0, 0, -1),
        new Vec3(1, 0, 0),
        new Vec3(0, 1, 0),
        new Vec3(0, 0, 1),
    };

    private bool IsInBound(Vec3 pos)
    {
        return (pos.x >= 0 && pos.x < Size.x)
            && (pos.y >= 0 && pos.y < Size.y)
            && (pos.z >= 0 && pos.z < Size.z);
    }

    public int GetComponentSize(Vec3 pos)
    {
        var initial = new[] {pos};
        var set = new HashSet<Vec3>(initial);
        var queue = new Queue<Vec3>(initial);
        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            var p = queue.Dequeue();
            foreach (var dir in _dirs)
            {
                var p1 = p + dir;
                if (IsInBound(p1))
                {
                    if (Get(p1) && set.Add(p1))
                        queue.Enqueue(p1);
                }
                else
                {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
        return set.Count;
    }
}
```

---

**Is there any more efficient data structure?**

I saw this http://www.diku.dk/PATH05/CRC-book1.pdf (section 1.4) but it seems really complicated. Maybe there are simpler solutions for a lattice graph?

**PS**: It's okay to answer in any programming language you like. I'm using C# here just because my program is written in C#.